# uwsgi and django: ImportError: No module named __future__

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

when I try to deploy my django page uWSGI tells:

```
...
added /env/project/ to pythonpath.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/project/project/wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
ImportError: No module named __future__
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

i tried

```
django-admin.py startproject project
```

to test with a fresh project, but it doesnt work either. I also played arround with the project.ini and reinstalled the virtualenv (tried: 2.7 3.0 3.3). Nothing helps.

Nginx and uWSGI are running in a chrooted jail. Django is installed with easy_install-2.7 in a virtualenv-2.7.

I dont really understand what is happening here. I think it has to do with the update to django version 1.5.

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: From the same virtualenv, try this in the interactive console: `import __future__`. Does that work? If it doesn't, your Python might be broken.

Comment: I have the same issue and I can make `import __future__` from my virtualenv. It seems that Uwsgi fails working with the virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons for this. Most likely it is a permissions issue. `uwsgi` is running as a user that doesn't have read access to the python files in the virtualenv.

### Check the virtualenv

In any case, the first step is to source the virtualenv and check that the import works.

```
. /path/to/venv/activate/script
python -c 'import __future__'
```

If that works, then you know your virtualenv is in good shape.

### Check that the module is in python's module search path

Now the error is isolated to uwsgi's use of that virtualenv. Run the following snippet to find the location of the `__future__` module.

```
python -c 'import __future__; print __future__.__file__'
```

When uwsgi runs python, it must run it as a user and with an environment. If the environment is wrong, python won't be able to find its modules. Ensure that the location of the `__future__` module is in python's module search path.

```
# Open /env/project/project/wsgi.py and add the following lines to the
# beginning.
import sys; print sys.path
```

Restart uwsgi and look for that printed list of directories. You should find that one of those directories contains the path to `__future__`'s module. If it doesn't then you'll need to figure out how to correct that path.

### Check that uwsgi has permissions to read/access the module

Granted that the directory is present, you need to ensure that the file permissions would allow uwsgi to load that module.

```
sudo -u <uwsgi user> -c python /path/to/__future__/module.py
```

Likely the culprit is the uwsgi user doesn't have permissions.